# How can I configure a gamepad in Planetside?

Tags: controllers, planetside

Recently I downloaded the Original Planetside. I want to use my logitech dual action gamepad with it, however, I can't seem to configure the buttons on the controller in game. Particularly, I went to the joystick menu in the game and was able to set the left thumb stick to look up, down, left, right and the other thumbstick to strafe left and right. The drop downs only provided options to select the 2 axis's on the left thumbstick and the horizontal axis on the right. I wasn't able to configure any of the controller buttons. They do appear to be detected by the game, as they light up in the settings menu when I press the corresponding button. However, I cannot map them to any game function.

This is an old game, others are bound to have done this successfully. Also, this is one of the most common models of gamepads for pc gaming. Has anyone successfully confured this, and could they provide a tutorial on how.

---

**Update:**
This is a recent screenshop of the in game menus. The issue where one of the joystick's axis did not appear in the drop down seems to have resolved itself. However, I am still at a loss in how to configure certain controls to the gamepad. I can configure strafing and the direction the camera points to the joysticks, but I still can't find how to set forward and backward movements to the joysticks.
[image: The Joystick Configuration Menu from the game]

[image: Keymapping menu from the game]

Comment: This may be irrelevant, but I am running the game on a Linux OS, Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail 32 bit. I don't think that will affect how the in game menus interact with you.